# Angular Ui data-grid filtering issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using the angular ui datagrid framework and I need to filter values with unique identifiers.
I have the following code:

```
var column = 
{name: 'distrito', field: 'distrito.id', type: 'number', 
displayName: 'Distrito', enableCellEdit: true, width: '135', 
cellFilter:'listagemFacesFilter:editDropdownOptionsArray:editDropdownIdLabel:editDropdownValueLabel:row.entity.distrito.distrito', 
editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor', 
editDropdownIdLabel: 'id', editDropdownValueLabel: 'distrito', editDropdownOptionsArray: $scope.listaDistritos, 
filter: {type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT, selectOptions: $scope.listaDistritosFiltro}
};
```

the $scope.listaDistritosFiltro is a arraylist with id (int) and value
(function returns arraylist)

The selection, filter all id's with example: id= 1 and id =12 at the same time and i need only results with id=1 or id=12.

I think the selection filter is filtering with string type.

Someone can help me, please.

Thanks.
Best Regards,
SMDC

Comment: Can you try to format your code to make it easier to read

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for this filter -

```
 type: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT
```